# Is aspartame a mind control drug?

Tags: mind-control, aspartame

In casual conversation about a popular fizzy soft drink, one of my colleagues said "You do know aspartame is a mind control drug, right?"

So I searched for "aspartame mind control drug" and found this article:

- [Aspartame as a Mind-Control Agent](http://freedomcrowsnest.wizardofthenorth.ca/viewtopic.php?t=25753)

> To the CIA, the desired effect is that aspartame makes the brain more susceptible to programming by ELF (extra low frequency) transmission. This is because, with a lower average action potential threshold, the brain more easily “locks on” to the ELF signal. In effect, an ELF pulse of between 1-13hz can induce specific neuron impulse frequencies. Specific frequencies are directly associated with specific emotions. Even more, specific transmissions can subconsciously implant the interference patterns associated with the holographic brain-imprint of sights, sounds, memories, and thoughts.
>
> [...]
>
> As an ulcer drug, aspartame was next to worthless. As a mind-control drug, however, as CIA scientists at Searle discovered, it was highly effective at decreasing the overall ability of the individual to resist electromagnetic mind-control.

The Skeptoid have a 2008 article, *[The Truth about Aspartame](http://skeptoid.com/episodes/4127)*, which critically examines a number of claims about Aspartame. It mentions the [mind-control claims](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8kgJfw699E), but doesn't address them.

Is there any evidence that aspartame is a mind control drug?

Comment: Someone has put both way too much and way too little thought into this.

Comment: I would argue from chemistry: Aspartame is a dipeptide. Specifically, it's a methyl ester of aspartic acid and phenylalanine. There are many naturally occurring [dipeptides in your body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipeptide). What unique physical property does this one dipeptide have over all of the others that allows it to be used for mind control? If someone is going to convince me that aspartame is used for mind control, they need to point out the unique moiety that's responsible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aspartame is recommended as a food additive after [review](http://www.fda.gov/food/ingredientspackaginglabeling/foodadditivesingredients/ucm397725.htm#Aspartame) by FDA on scientific data regarding the safety of aspartame in food and the conclusions was that it is safe for the general population to consume except for people with a rare hereditary disease known as phenylketonuria (PKU) unable to metabolize phenylalanine, a component of aspartame.

As of 2014, in response to citizen Betty Martini's petition mentioned [here](http://www.regulations.gov/#!documentDetail;D=FDA-2002-P-0247-0023) and Paul Stoller MD's petition mentioned [here](http://www.regulations.gov/#!documentDetail;D=FDA-2009-P-0156-0003), FDA found no credible evidence for brain effects after reviewing aspartame safety which matches aspartame safety review data from various other regulatory [agencies](http://www.foodstandards.gov.au/consumer/additives/aspartame/pages/default.aspx).

Referring to a report on MKULTRA program employed by [CIA](http://www.nytimes.com/packages/pdf/national/13inmate_ProjectMKULTRA.pdf) to counter perceived Soviet and Chinese advances in brainwashing techniques, aspartame was not one of the substances disclosed to cause hallucinogenic effect. The known halluciongens tested were LSD and quinuclidinyl benzilate, code-named BZ. The other experiments involved chemicals such as heroin, morphine, temazepam (used under code name MKSEARCH), mescaline, psilocybin, scopolamine, marijuana, alcohol, sodium pentothal, barbiturate IV and amphetamine IV in each arm.

> Someday it may be possible to stimulate electronically or chemically a specific network of neurons to cause specific sounds or sights of the experimenter’s choosing to emerge in a person's consciousness. But this is not possible today. Even if it were possible, it would not necessarily follow that a person would obey a command to assassinate the president just because he heard a voice telling him to do so. Hearing voices is one thing. Feeling compelled to obey them is quite another.
>
> If we define mind control as the successful control of the thoughts and actions of another without his or her  consent, mind control exists only in fantasy. Unfortunately, that does not mean that it will always be [thus](http://skepdic.com/mindcont.html).

Extremely low frequency electromagnetic fields (EMF) are known to surround home appliances as well as high-voltage electrical transmission lines and transformers. Evidence of health effects such as influence on brain from EMF is inconclusive referring to Amir Raz, assistant professor of clinical neuroscience at Columbia [University](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/could-certain-frequencies/).

> **Evidence of health effects from EMF, including their influence on the brain, is inconclusive, and the probability that EMF exposure is a genuine health hazard is currently small.** Nevertheless, exposure to high levels of nonionizing energy, such as at radio wave frequencies, can damage the structure and function of the nervous system. For example, microwave frequencies below 3,000 megahertz can penetrate the outer layers of the skin, be absorbed in the underlying tissues, and result in all of the known biological effects of heating, including burns, cataracts, and possibly death.

Comment: If the claim is that the CIA (a U.S. government agency) is behind this mind-control research, I don't think any report by the FDA (another U.S. agency, and certainly susceptible to whatever insidious suppression tactics the CIA uses) is useful to debunk it. Also, the claim is not that ELF is harmful or a health hazard, but rather that it is used to "program" or transmit information to the aspartame-softened mind.

Comment: I agree with @iamnotmaynard. Even people who don't fall for "mind control" conspiracy theories often put little faith in the FDA, especially for aspartame, where there are many claims, going back decades, of corporate collusion/corruption within the FDA to get the substance approved (although for the less nefarious reason of simple profit, rather than mind control).  So while I don't think that directly disqualifies FDA evidence from consideration (thus no -1 from me), it's not enough to consider the case closed.

Comment: @Iamnotmaynard-The claim talks about aspartame making the brain more susceptible to programming by ELF (extra low frequency) transmission. However, EMF (including extra low frequency transmission) influence on the brain is inconclusive per source provided. So this should mean that it does not only talk about health hazards but also incldues health effects i.e. influence on the brain. MKULTRA CIA's brainwashing project also did not involve aspartame.

Comment: @Flimzy-Mind control exists only in fantasy for now but someday it may be possible to stimulate electronically or chemically a specific network of neurons to cause specific sounds or sights of the experimenter’s choosing to emerge in a person's consciousness.

Comment: For the people criticising the source, what sort of source *would* you accept?